# Robot model is not displayed when loading a urdf file using the moveit setup assistant #786

Tags: ros-melodic, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have learned that this happened to Indigo before but I am using Melodic. the moveit-setup-assistant was working for me just last week. Suddenly, it does not display the robot after loading the model!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361112/robot-model-is-not-displayed-when-loading-a-urdf-file-using-the-moveit-setup-assistant-#786/) by [Victor Wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40929/victor-wu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2020-09-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-09-08**:
This is most likely [ros-planning/moveit#2286](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/2286) which has already been fixed.

> Robot model is not displayed when loading a urdf file using the moveit setup assistant #786

what is the `#786` you include in your title?

Edit: the issue you refer to. While a similar issue, it's so old it's unlikely to be related.

**Comment by [AlecPath](https://answers.ros.org/users/60654/alecpath/) on 2020-10-08**:
I too am having this issue.  Even loading moveit configurations that worked fine in the past (just a week or two ago) no longer show the robot. Rviz works fine (demo.launch or my own setups) I did just update my apt packages, I'm not sure how long it had been since I had done so.

Going to the "Robot Poses" tab and selecting a pose seems to make the robot show up and subsequently function as normal, except if I go back to the "Robot Poses" tab it crashes (seg fault).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue reported by the OP has been fixed.

Please refer to the issue I linked in my initial comment.

What hasn't happened yet, is a MoveIt *release* since it has been fixed.

So the binaries you are most likely using still have the problem.

There's little use in reporting the issue again, as it's a known one, and a solution is already available.

> Even loading moveit configurations that worked fine in the past (just a week or two ago) no longer show the robot

the issue is not caused by "new configurations", so loading old ones does not change anything or help.

I would suggest to check the linked issue and follow-up there.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0